# Tyk gateway with Nginx and Apache Tomcat 8 (ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: nginx, configuration, ibm-api-management, tyk

Just wondering what I am missing here when trying to create an API with Tyk Dashboard.

My setup is:

```
Nginx > Apache Tomcat 8 > Java Web Application > (database)
```

Nginx is already working, redirecting calls to apache tomcat at default port 8080.

Example: **tomcat.myserver.com/webapp/get/1**
200-OK

I have setup tyk-dashboard and tyk-gateway previously as follows using a custom node port 8011:

Tyk dashboard:

```
$ sudo /opt/tyk-dashboard/install/setup.sh --listenport=3000 --redishost=localhost --redisport=6379 --mongo=mongodb://127.0.0.1/tyk_analytics --tyk_api_hostname=$HOSTNAME --tyk_node_hostname=http://127.0.0.1 --tyk_node_port=8011 --portal_root=/portal --domain="dashboard.tyk-local.com"
```

Tyk gateway:

```
/opt/tyk-gateway/install/setup.sh --dashboard=1 --listenport=8011 --redishost=127.0.0.1 --redisport=6379 --domain=""
```

**/etc/hosts** already configured (not really needed):

```
127.0.0.1 dashboard.tyk-local.com
127.0.0.1 portal.tyk-local.com
```

Tyk Dashboard configurations (nothing special here):

- API name: foo
- Listen path: /foo
- API slug: foo
- Target URL: tomcat.myserver.com/webapp/

What URI I suppose to call? Is there any setup I need to add in Nginx?

1. myserver.com/foo 502 nginx
2. myserver.com:8011/foo does not respond
3. foo.myserver.com 502 nginx

(everything is running under the same server)

**SOLVED:**

Tyk Gateway configuration was incorrect.
Needed to add `--mongo` and remove `--domain` directives at setup.sh :

```
/opt/tyk-gateway/install/setup.sh --dashboard=1 --listenport=8011 --redishost=localhost --redisport=6379 --mongo=mongodb://127.0.0.1/tyk_analytics
```

So, calling curl -H "Authorization: null" 127.0.0.1:8011/foo
I get:

```
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    "error": "Key not authorised"                                                                                                                                                                                                         
}
```

Comment: Is the request to `http://myserver.com:8011/foo` stuck? Do you see any logs?

Comment: Yes. the log didn't change at all...

Comment: it shows the following at tyk-gateway.log:
[Jul  4 10:44:13] ERROR Instrumentation is enabled, but no connectionstring set for statsd

Comment: $ curl -H "Authorization: null" http://127.0.0.1:8011/foo
no response at all.. =[

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the `/foo` path. I think that was previously what the `/hello` path is. But it appears there is a key not authorized issue. If the call is made using the [Gateway API](https://tyk.io/docs/tyk-gateway-api/), then the `secret` value may be missing.  It is required when making calls to the gateway (except the hello and reload paths)

```
x-tyk-authorization: <your-secret>
```

However, since there is a dashboard present, then I would suggest using the [Dashboard APIs](https://tyk.io/docs/tyk-dashboard-api/) to create the API definition instead.